# How to fix token pattern in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, tokenize

I am using TfidfVectorizer from scikit-learn to extract features, 
And the settings are:

```
def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    stems = []
    for token in tokens:
        token = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]","", token)
        stems.append(EnglishStemmer().stem(token))
    return stems
```

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, lowercase=True, stop_words='english')

After feeding the training set to the vectorizer, I call

```
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

the output contains some duplicate words with space: e.g.

```
u'', u' ', u' low', u' lower', u'lower', u'lower ', u'lower high', u'lower low'
```

And the acceptable output should be:

```
u'low', u'lower', u'lower high', u'lower low'
```

How can I solve that? Thank you.

Comment: The input is a bunch of tweets from stocktwits.com which contains a lot of slang

Comment: The `stems` list in your `tokenize` function is a local variable and is born and dies with each call of the function.  Why are you bothering to build that list at all?  It can't possibly serve any purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I miss the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like the below,

```
>>> l = ['lower low', 'lower high','lower ', ' lower', u'lower', ' ', '', 'low']
>>> list(set(i.strip() for i in l if i!=' ' and i))
['lower', 'lower low', 'lower high', 'low']
```

Comment: So, what is the regular expression of <word><space><word> or <word> without punctuation or leading space?

Comment: what do you want to do with the above? What's you expected output?

Comment: I read the instruction from sklearn, maybe I can set the token_pattern in regex form. see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

Comment: i just answered this 'how to remove dulicates,empty strings in' `u'', u' ', u' low', u' lower', u'lower', u'lower ', u'lower high', u'lower low'`